# Chat message mouse-over actions obscure links at end of line

Tags: bug, chat

The chat message mouse-over actions obscure the end of the chat message, which is not normally an issue unless there is a link there:

[image]

Becomes, on mouse-over:

[image]

And the link at the end of the line cannot be clicked, as the action icons overlap it when the mouse is moved to click the link. Only negatively affects links at the end of the line that are narrower than the action icon set. Workaround is to resize the chat window so it wraps, or to adjust zoom (thanks [rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252888/chat-message-mouse-over-actions-obscure-links-at-end-of-line?noredirect=1#comment825826_252888)).

Perhaps the icons could go to the right of the text in the spacing between the chat area and the star wall; there is a decent amount of space there. The only other option I can think of is making the actions push the text over, which could get irritating with line height changes from wrapping. [Travis J](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252888/chat-message-mouse-over-actions-obscure-links-at-end-of-line#comment825825_252888) also presents the option of making the actions disappear after a short time.

Comment: This seems like such a narrowly scoped bug, because not many people use the word "here" as the name for a link :P Any fix to this narrow case may have more annoying side affects to chat in general.

Comment: @TravisJ Yes, it's very narrow. I won't lose sleep over a [tag:status-declined]. The other option is to make smokey say "A command list is available [right here, buddy]."

Comment: On the other hand, I was able to reproduce this issue. One possible suggestion (which probably would not be best either due to larger ramifications) would be to have the option group simply fade out and remove after some time window (1.5s?).

Comment: An easy workaround is [zooming a little bit..](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IFwlw.png)

Comment: Re: [right here, buddy] From a UX standpoint, I like larger descriptive links myself. So perhaps something along the lines of *A [command list] is also available.*

Comment: @TravisJ [Beat you to it.](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/pull/52) :) Although I like your version better, but I'm done bugging ProgramFOX with pull requests for the day.

Comment: @JasonC - Bigger is better! haha I think the entire line as a link is good as well

Comment: @TimStone But mine's way better! (Thanks for digging that up.)

Comment: In retrospect I suppose I could have duped them in the other direction, sorry :P